# Is it a typo in the book?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently reading the Linear Algebra appendix for a "control systems theory" book and I have trouble with this part:
[image]

If $n_i$ indicates the geometric multiplicity assosiated with each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$
Then in the equation $Av_i^j = \lambda_iv_i^j$ , the values of $i$ and $j$ should be reversed , shouldn't be? Because for instance for the eigen value $l_1$ , we assoaciated with the set of vectors : $v_1^1,v_2^1,..,v_{n_1}^1$ which shows that $i$ runs to $[1,n_1]$ whereas $j=1$ and in general $j$ stands for the current eigen value which takes values from $1$ to $d$

Comment: Looks like a typo, yes

Answer (score 2):

Right. There are $d$ distinct Eigenvalues and in the notation of the Eigenvectors, the upper index denotes the Eigenvalue. Then there is a contradiction with $v_i^j$ if $i=1,\cdots,d$.

A correct result is $Av_j^i=\lambda_iv_j^i$, for $i=1,\cdots d$ and $j=1,\cdots,n_i$.